# Where are the Chinese lanterns found?

Tags: ok-golf

I've found 2, one was Tsukimi garden hole 7, the other I found a while ago, and am fairly sure was Tsukimi garden but I don't remember the hole.

Can't find the others anywhere, anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lanterns are located on levels:

1-4 (Long Lake County, Hole 4)
3-7 (Tsukimi Garden, Hole 7)
5-3 (Buchan Bay, Hole 3)
7-9 (Oakford Woods, Hole 9)
8-5 (Paris Rooftops, Hole 5)
9-5 (Kaski Pass, Hole 5)
11-1 (Juovlastállu Park, Hole 1)
12-3 (Greatest Hits, Hole 3)